# Why is [M(AB)2] a geometrical isomer?

Tags: coordination-compounds, stereochemistry, isomers, cis-trans-isomerism

Our teacher told us that for coordination number 4 and tetrahedral shape $\ce{[M(AB)2]}$ doesn't have a plane of symmetry, so it shows optical isomerism.

What if we take a plane passing through the two $\ce{A}$'s so the $\ce{B's}$ will be the mirror image of each other? Am I wrong?

Comment: AB is implied to mean a bidentate ligand with a bridge between A and B. See where the bridge will go in the mirror.

Comment: Do we see the bonds as well while considering the mirror image?

Comment: In all likeness, the bridges consist of quite a few atoms, not just bonds.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I understood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to record the question as answered:

- If you had separate A and B ligands with no ligand-ligand bonds, then the complex would have a plane (actually two planes) of symmetry and would not be chiral.
- But when you have a bridge between each A ligand and a separate B ligand, the bridges do not conform with the above plane(s) of symmetry and so those symmetry planes are lost. Thereby the complex becomes chiral.